# Find security packages installation history on Debian

Tags: debian, security, update, history

I need your help. 
I need to find out the date of the last installation of security packages on debian servers.

I have been looking for a solution based on log files (dpkg.log, history.log) but it seems there's no information to identify a security update.

Do you have any ideas ? 
PS: I don't want to use unanttended-upgrade and its logfiles.

Thank you.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12578/list-packages-on-an-apt-based-system-by-installation-date

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. I have already seen this thread, but my problem is I cannot identify security package in the output. A solution could be to fetch all the security packages and compare them to the list of installed/updated package. I'am looking for a way to get the full list of security packages according to the version of Debian.

Answer (score 0):

For the future, you'll want to install and use `apt-listchanges` - it can/will provide a summary on installation and updates, including notices if an update is security related.  http://jxf.me/entries/better-apt-ubuntu/

In the mean time, for the past, the closest that is easy to get I think is the contents of the `/var/log/apt/history*` files.  A rather large (sorry) example snippet of my last `dist-upgrade`.  Notice nothing specific about security updates or which repo each package is from...

Ok, way too large and no way to format nicely.  pastebin to the rescue! `/var/log/apt/history.log` snippet for a `dist-upgrade` is at https://termbin.com/wqtt

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. apt-listchanges takes a package as a parameter. I need to get the last security package installed and its date. Same issue with history.log, I don't know how to identify a security package in the output.